# Screen reader cannot read number input values on Chrome

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a spinbutton that looks something like this:

```
<input type="number" name="amountMonthly" id="amount-monthly_0" class="formInput" required="required" tabindex="70" aria-describedby="amountMonthlyInfo" aria-labelledby="amountMonthlyLbl">
```

The expected behavior when using a screen reader (I use NVDA) is have it read the label once, and read the new value with each change in the spinbutton. Here is how this element is read in three states on two different browsers.

```
FIREFOX: Empty field selected (in focus)
    [label] spinbutton invalid entry required [description] edit blank
FIREFOX: press up button (increment)
    [number on screen]
FIREFOX: selected the entire numerical value (call it num)
    [first length-of-num characters of label] selected

CHROME: Empty field selected (in focus)
    [label] spinbutton editable invalid entry required [description] [label]
CHROME: press up button (increment)
    [label]
CHROME: selected the entire numerical value (call it num)
    [first length-of-num characters of label] selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug with Chrome itself. I found an open issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=730965) for anyone checking this question in the future.. There's also a related ticket to NVDA which can be found [here](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/5422).